# Update value in a column based on another column in the same table

Tags: mysql

I cannot seem to figure this out, I have the following table:

Daily Schedules

| Id | ScheduleId | Date | ActivityId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2021-04-08 | 20 |
| 2 | 5 | 2021-04-01 | 25 |
| 3 | 6 | 2021-04-08 | 21 |
| 4 | 6 | 2021-04-01 | 26 |

I want to update the ActivityId for the rows with the same ScheduleId based on the date, so the 20 becomes 25 and the 21 becomes 26. How can I do it while avoiding a circular reference?

Comment: Get `ActivityId` for minimal `Date` per `ScheduleId` in subquery, use this value for updating another table copy.

Comment: *How can I do it while avoiding a circular reference?* UPDATE canot produce "circular reference" - each row is updated (if it is updated, of course) only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE ( SELECT ScheduleId, MIN(`Date`) `Date`
         FROM table t1
         GROUP BY ScheduleId ) t2
  JOIN table t3 USING (ScheduleId, `Date`)
  JOIN table t4 USING (ScheduleId)
SET t4.ActivityId = t3.ActivityId
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! If I wanted to update the ActivityId of a specific date based on another date, where should I put the condition? For example, making the 3rd of march have the same activity as the 6th for all schedules or a specific one

Comment: @Spirotrack *I wanted to update the ActivityId of a specific date based on another date, where should I put the condition?* In this case you must remove subquery `t2` at all, and add WHERE which sets the date which you want to update in `t4`, and the date which you want to obtain from in `t3`. Like `WHERE t3.date = '2021-04-01' AND t4.date = '2021-04-08'`.